# CollectionView inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

So my problem is that every time that I'm trying to scroll, scroll view doesn't work. Only the scroll of the collection view is working.

I have my `ViewController` and this subviews:

```
. View
.. Scrollview
... Label
... Image 
... Label
... CollectionView (column of 2)
```

I tried to disable scroll in collection view but nothing is working as expected.

Comment: It could depend on many things, can you share your code?

Comment: I didn't code nothing about the scrollview (I did everything in interface builder ) . I Just added items to the collection view which I don't think is important in this problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not considered good practice to put an `UICollectionView` inside a `UIScrollView` because this will result in some unwanted behavior since `UICollectionView` is a descendant of the `UIScrollView` class.

Instead of having a `UIScrollView` with `Label, Image, Label, CollectionView`, you could remove the `UIScrollView` and add a `UICollectionReusableView` as a header to the `UICollectionView`. Inside this header you can put the `Label, Image, Label` and that view will always stay on top of the `UICollectionView` section you created the header for.

You could have a go at this and then come back to us if you run in to some problems :)

[UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview)

[Collection View Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html)

Comment: I'm going to try this, Thanks.

Comment: Just for others. I used a uicollectionview inside a scrollview and it worked. so far no unusual behavoir.

Comment: But what about scrollable ability in the view controller without scrollview, tell me please?

Comment: @V777 I'm sorry, I don't understand the scenario. You should try to implement it, and then create a separate question if you don't find any relevant question with an answer elsewhere.

Comment: 1)collection view header has behaviour other than usual view; 2)what if need to place additional views near `UICollectionView` but I don't need "reusable" behaviour and collection cells are too complex in comparison to usual views?

Answer (score 5):

From the information in the question it's hard to give a detailed answer. Just a little tip. You should carefully check 2 important things, when your are working with `UIScrollView`:

1. Autolayout constraints of scroll view subviews.
2. `contentSize` of your scroll view.

Maybe this will help.

There are also some tips even you choose to disable scrollable for uicollectionView:

1. You need a fix height for uicollectionView in autolayout, or that will  give you a warning: scrollview need y position or height.
2. You need a constraint outlet to collectionView's height, and adjust its value to contentSize in your code. Such as in viewDidLoad. That means you cannot implement this only using AutoLayout.