CollectionView in MAUI is slower than Xamarin
I'm using Collection View to display the list of data in a table format, similar to a structured table.

The table must be both horizontally and vertically scrollable. In the MAUI Collection View, I'm facing two issues.

In order to scroll the Collection View both horizontally and vertically, I'm placing the Collection View inside the Scroll View. The Scroll View makes the Collection View horizontally scrollable, and the Collection View itself is vertically scrollable.

When using a Collection View along with a Scroll View, the process of binding the data takes longer. When the Scroll View is not present, the rendering process occurs as quickly as possible.
Is it possible to make the Collection View scrollable both horizontally and vertically without the Scroll View?


The scrolling performance of the Collection View is poor & laggy in MAUI. It works fine in Xamarin. The same UI works well in Xamarin. 

<ScrollView
    Padding="0"
    Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid
        ColumnSpacing="0"
        RowDefinitions="27,auto"
        RowSpacing="1.5"
        WidthRequest="{Binding TableWidth}">
       <---- Table Header binding ----->
        <CollectionView
            Grid.Row="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TableHeaders}"
            HeightRequest="25"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                        WidthRequest="{Binding Width}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="0" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        </CollectionView>
        <---- Table Content binding ----->
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="ColumnData"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TableCellDetails}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                        <CollectionView
                            x:Name="Item"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding CellDetails}"
                            HeightRequest="22">
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label
                                        LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                                        WidthRequest="{Binding Width}">
                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Dispatch}, Path=BindingContext.SelectedItem}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Label>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="0" />
                            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        </CollectionView>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="2" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>


What about HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and VerticalScrollBarVisibility

CollectionView inside a ScrollView is a recipe for disaster in most cases, I have a question, why do you want to scroll both vertically and horizontally, I have never really seen this requirement before...

@FreakyAli, a recipe for disaster specifically on Android

@MustafaMutasim Not just Android https://stackoverflow.com/a/47174824/7462031

I will check thanks, I've said that based on tests to Apple iPhone 6 & Samsung Note 9, the latter is very laggy and unresponsive.

@FreakyAli, We will set the width for each label. When the label's width exceeds the width of the device, we must obviously scroll horizontally to see the full content.

@MustafaMutasim The reason it's considered bad practice has less to do with how to respond and more to do with nesting, ListView and RecyclerView in Android and UICollectionView and UILIstView in iOS actually inherit from their ScrollView's internally and hence you are basically nesting two ScrollViews which causes issues
